# Weird issue with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I'd like to go to a specific character, in a specific line in my text file with fstream.

For exemple i want to go to line 2, i do this :

```
stream.ignore(20, '\n'); // because i have 20 characters in each line.
```

It works fine, but when i try to move in this line:

```
stream.seekg(1, ios::cur); // move 1 char from the current position.
```

And i test the output:

```
char test;
stream >> test;
```

It gives me a character in the middle of line 3 ! ( i am supposed to be on line 2)

And then i've checked if my current position is ok with :

```
stream.seekg(0, ios::cur);
stream >> char;
```

And it was ok, it gives me the char in the beginning of line 2. But as you see when i replace 0 by 1 it gives me a character in the middle of line 3 ! :/ Isn't supposed to move by 1 char ?

Do you have any idea why it does this ?

I am making a tile based isometric engine and i need to save and read my database in a text file. The area of the map which i am saving/reading needs to be on my view, so i have to read from a minx char to a maxx char, and miny(line) char to a maxy(line).

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your text file or excerpt from it?

Comment: This is the text file that i've used for testing: http://pastebin.com/Lpm0DUnN

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a sign/unsigned issue? Try using unsigned char. Edit(saw your text file): okay, never mind.

Comment: just tested with unsigned char, and it didn't help.

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine. Before you move to the next line, see what the current position is using stream.tellg(). Since you're moving from ios::cur, and if your getpointer is not set at the beginning of the file, then you won't move to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: @user3134405 By the way, isn't \n two characters (13 10) is ignore performing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/110602/problem-with-seekg states that the file has to be opened in binary mode for seekg to function reliably with offset. Try that.

Comment: This could be the issue, I still don't understand why it works on my computer. To open a file in binary: stream("data.txt", ios::binary);

Comment: when i try with binary the if(stream) condition is false because my output is empty. when i do without the condition my output is, now at -1, moved to -1, got u from -1

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3134405 What do you mean your output is empty? fstream data("data.txt", ios_base::in|ios_base::binary); doesn't work for you?

Comment: fstream data("data.txt", ios_base::in|ios_base::binary); , i think it worked ! now at 0, moved to 20, got b from 23

Comment: but i am supposed to get 't', from 2nd character from 2nd line no ?

Comment: @user3134405 I don't think so. I believe your cal to ignore reached the line break and your call to seek moved past it to the next character which is 'b'.

Comment: @o_weisman yeah but even without seek call or seek(0, ios::cur) i have the char 'b'. Anyway  i can reach 't' by doing seek(3, ios::cur) ( i think it's be cause '/n' = 2 and the 'b' = 1 ) It's gonna be hard to manage this with my isometric engine...

Comment: @user3134405 Shouldn't it be '\n'?

Comment: @o_weisman i understand why i got 'b' and not '\n', it's because  '\n' is not a char and i request a char. So it gives me the next char which is in 23

Comment: Btw, my code doesn't exactly specify the position where the character was extracted. There should be a -1 there because the tellg is incremented after you get a character, so it displays 23, which is the current position, which is after where you extracted that character. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cout<<"Now at "<<stream.tellg()<<endl;

stream.ignore(20,'\n');

cout<<"Moved to "<<stream.tellg()<<endl;

stream.seekg(1, ios::cur);

char test;
stream>>test;
cout<<"Got character "<<test<<" from position "<<stream.tellg()<<endl;
```

Comment: Output is : Now at 0, Moved to 45, Got character a from position 72.

Comment: I deleted and created my file again, now i have this : Now at 0, Moved to 39, a from position 59

Comment: @user3134405 Try replacing '\n' with 13, see what happens.

Comment: sorry it was : Now at 0, move to 40, a from 60. With '/n' replaced by 13 i have, 0, 39, a from 59.

Comment: Can you post  the code beginning from when you declare stream?

Comment: @user3134405 Try adding a check to see if stream.good() == true after each operation on stream

Comment: I copied your code and ran it. There is nothing wrong. It moves to 20, extracts the character then the final position is 23. I'm not sure what the problem is, but the code is correct.

Comment: Ok, one last try. I just read that "Do not use the second member function with text files, because Standard C++ does not support relative seeks in text files." on MSDN regarding seekg() function. Try absolute seek with just one paramter seekg(position)

Comment: with  seekg(1) i have : now at 0, moved to 39, a from pos 21

Comment: @user3134405 see my new answer